# Bracket one of two roots in root finding algorithm for roots of a multivariate function

Tags: python, math, scipy

Apologies for the (maybe misleading) title and the probably confusing question itself, i struggle a lot with wording my problem and especially compressing it into one sentence for the title. I want to find the roots of a function `f(w, t, some_other_args)` with two variables, `w` and `t`, using python. The real function structure is really long and complicated, you can find it on the end of this post. The important thing is that it contains the following line:

```
k = 1.5 * m.sqrt((1.0 - w) / (1.0 - 0.25 * w))
```

This means that `w` can't exceed 1, because that would lead to calculating the square root of a negative number, which, of course, is impossible. I have algorithms for calculating the approximate values of `w` and `t` using other values in my function, but they are very inaccurate.

So, i try to calculate the roots with `scipy.optimize.fsolve` (after trying literally every root finding algorithm i could find online, i found this one to be the best for my function) using these approximate values as starting points, which would look like this:

```
solution = optimize.fsolve(f, x0=np.array([t_approx, w_approx]), args=(some_other_args))
```

For most values, this works perfectly fine. If `w` is too close to 1, however, there always comes a point when `fsolve` tries some value bigger than 1 for `w`, which, in turn, raises a `ValueError`(because calculating the root of a negative number is mathematically impossible). This is an example printing out the values that `fsolve`is using, where `w` should be somewhere around 0.997:

```
w_approx: 0.9960090844989311
t_approx: 24.26777844720981
Values: t:24.26777844720981, w:0.9960090844989311
Values: t:24.26777844720981, w:0.9960090844989311
Values: t:24.26777844720981, w:0.9960090844989311
Values: t:24.267778808827888, w:0.9960090844989311
Values: t:24.26777844720981, w:0.996009099340623
Values: t:16.319554685876746, w:1.0096680915775516
      solution = optimize.fsolve(f, x0=np.array([t_approx, w_approx]), args=(some_other_args))
    File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 148, in fsolve
      res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 227, in _root_hybr
      ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    File "C:\Users\...\algorithm.py", line 9, in f
      k = 1.5 * m.sqrt((1.0 - w) / (1.0 - 0.25 * w))
ValueError: math domain error
```

So, how can i tell `optimize.fsolve` that `w` can't get bigger than 1? Or what are alternative algorithms for doing something like this (i know about `brentq` and so on, but all of those require giving an interval for *both* roots, which i don't want to do.)?

---

Code for testing (What's important to note here: even though `func` theoretically is supposed to calculate `R` and `T` given `t` and `w`, i have to use it the other way around. It's a bit clunky, but i simply don't manage to rewrite the function so that it accepts `T, R` to calculate `t, w` - it's a bit too much for my mediocre mathematical expertise ;)) :

```
import math as m
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np


def func(t, w, r_1, r_2, r_3):

    k = 1.5 * m.sqrt((1.0 - w) / (1.0 - 0.25 * w))

    k23 = 2 * k / 3

    z1 = 1 / (1 + k23)
    z2 = 1 / (1 - k23)
    z3 = 3 * ((1 / 5 + r_1 - r_2 - 1 / 5 * r_1 * r_2) / (z1 - r_2 * z2)) * m.exp(t * (k - 1))
    z4 = -(z2 - r_2 * z1) / (z1 - r_2 * z2) * m.exp(2 * k * t)
    z5 = -(z1 - r_2 * z2) / (z2 - r_2 * z1)
    z6 = 3 * (1 - r_2 / 5) / (z2 - r_2 * z1)

    beta_t = r_3 / (z2 / z1 * m.exp(2 * k * t) + z5) * (z6 - 3 / (5 * z1) * m.exp(t * (k - 1)))
    alpha_t = beta_t * z5 - r_3 * z6

    beta_r = (z3 - r_1 / 5 / z2 * m.exp(-2 * t) * 3 - 3 / z2) / (z1 / z2 + z4)
    alpha_r = -z1 / z2 * beta_r - 3 / z2 - 3 / 5 * r_1 / z2 * m.exp(-2 * t)

    It_1 = 1 / 4 * w / (1 - 8 / 5 * w) * (alpha_t * z2 * m.exp(-k * t) + beta_t * z1 * m.exp(k * t) + 3 * r_3 * m.exp(-t))

    Ir_1 = (1 / 4 * w / (1 - 8 / 5 * w)) * (z1 * alpha_r + z2 * beta_r + 3 / 5 + 3 * r_1 * m.exp(-2 * t))

    T = It_1 + m.exp(-t) * r_3
    R = Ir_1 + m.exp(-2 * t) * r_1

    return [T, R]


def calc_1(t, w, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    t_begin = float(t[0])
    T_new, R_new = func(t_begin, w, r_1, r_2, r_3)
    a = abs(-1 + T_new/T)
    b = abs(-1 + R_new/R)
    return np.array([a, b])


def calc_2(x, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    t = x[0]
    w = x[1]
    T_new, R_new = func(t, w, r_1, r_2, r_3)
    a = abs(T - T_new)
    b = abs(R - R_new)
    return np.array([a, b])


def approximate_w(R):
    k = (1 - R) / (R + 2 / 3)
    w_approx = (1 - ((2 / 3 * k) ** 2)) / (1 - ((1 / 3 * k) ** 2))
    return w_approx


def approximate_t(w, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    t = optimize.root(calc_1, x0=np.array([10, 0]), args=(w, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3))
    return t.x[0]


def solve(T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    w_x = approximate_w(R)
    t_x = approximate_t(w_x, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3)
    sol = optimize.fsolve(calc_2, x0=np.array([t_x, w_x]), args=(T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3))
    return sol


# Values for testing:
T = 0.09986490557943692
R = 0.8918728343037964
r_1 = 0
r_2 = 0
r_3 = 1

print(solve(T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3))
```

Comment: Do you have a(n *interpretation-driven*) finite lower bound for `w` ?

Comment: i know that `w` lies always between 0 and 1.

Comment: Depending on your actual function, you could try to use `scipy.optimize.minimze`, which allows to pass constraints, maybe even `least_squares`.

Comment: i tried both of them some time ago, there were some other problems with them, but tbh i don't remember exactly - i will look into it again.

Comment: using `optimize.minimize` raises the following Error:`File "C:\Users\...\optimize\optimize.py", line 663, in _approx_fprime_helper
    grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reported error occurs as `fsolve` can not deal with the implicit restrictions in the conversion of `w` to `k`. This can be solved radically by inverting that dependence, making `func` dependent on `t` and `k` instead.

```
def w2k(w): return 3 * m.sqrt((1.0 - w) / (4.0 - w))
    #k = 1.5 * m.sqrt((1.0 - w) / (1.0 - 0.25 * w))
    # (k/3)**2 * (4-w)= 1-w 
def k2w(k): return 4 - 3/(1-(k/3)**2)

def func(t, k, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    w = k2w(k)
    print "t=%20.15f, k=%20.15f, w=%20.15f"%(t,k,w)
    ...
```

Then remove the absolute values from the function values in `calc1` and `calc2`. This only renders your solutions as non-differentiable points which is bad for any root-finding algorithm. Sign changes and smooth roots are good for Newton-like methods.

```
def calc_2(x, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    t = x[0]
    k = x[1]
    T_new, R_new = func(t, k, r_1, r_2, r_3)
    a = T - T_new
    b = R - R_new
    return np.array([a, b])
```

It makes not much sense to find the value for `t` by solving the equation keeping `w` resp. `k` fixed, it just doubles the computational effort.

```
def approximate_k(R):
    k = (1 - R) / (R + 2 / 3)
    return k

def solve(T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    k_x = approximate_k(R)
    t_x = 10
    sol = optimize.fsolve(calc_2, x0=np.array([t_x, k_x]), args=(T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3))
    return sol

t,k = solve(T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3)
print "t=%20.15f, k=%20.15f, w=%20.15f"%(t, k, k2w(k))
```

With these modifications the solution

```
t=  14.860121342410327, k=   0.026653140486605, w=   0.999763184675043
```

is found within 15 function evaluations.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to think this through! Looks promising, i will try it out rn. One question: in `solve`, is it intentional that you give `w_x` instead of `k_x` in the `x0`array? if so, where does `w_x`come from in this case?

Comment: No, of course not, there is no such variable defined at that point. I missed that when replacing the variable names. Thanks.

Comment: I really like this solution, and it worked with some tiny modifications! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What about [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)ing the argument that you want to constrain? I mean, inside `f`, you could do

```
import numpy as np

def f(free_w, ...):
    w = 1/(1 + np.exp(-free_w)) # w will always lie between 0 and 1
    ...
    return zeros
```

And then, you would just have to apply the same logistic-transformation to the solution value of `free_w` to get `w`*. See

```
solution = optimize.fsolve(f, x0=np.array([t_approx, w_approx]), args=(some_other_args))
free_w   = solution[0]
w        = 1/(1 + np.exp(-free_w))
```

Comment: Any question @Flob ?

Comment: Wouldn't you lose precision if `w` is close to 0 or 1 i.e. `free_w` approaches ±∞?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog It *all* depends on the tolerance you set for your `zeros`. But in practice, and with highly restrictive `tol` values, I always have my constraints met far before I loose precision.

Comment: like this `free_w = 1/(1 + np.exp(-w))` at the end of my algorithm?

Comment: meowgoesthedog is right, but there is no need to apply the reciprocal function @Flob.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea, thank you. But using this gives me mathematical errors at some other points of my calculation (`ZeroDivisionError` e.g.) and `t` gets close to -39000, where it should instead be around 24...

Comment: @Flob you haven't shown what `t` is and how it relates to `w`. Paste the function in your post or add a link to it.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog look at my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483474/finding-values-for-two-variables-of-a-multivariate-function-given-the-results) concerning the exact same Problem (which didn't get an answer back then...)

Comment: @Flob. I would like to replicate your results but I cannot. What is your `some_other_args` ? `1,0,1` ?

Comment: in my other question, that i linked in the comment above, i gave some values for testing

Comment: You did. But those value make no sense. Your system cannot be solved if some of its degrees of freedom are cancelled as you do.

Comment: i tried to simplify the whole thing for this question, because the way i asked last time, i couldn't get an answer. The thing i would have to do is rewrite my function to be abe to calculate `w` and `t` in dependency of `R` and `T`, but looking at the function you might understand that thats is simply impossible.

Comment: @Flob We have no time to look at your function man. I just want to copy the whole thing and replicate your results. I don't understand you. Do you want to get some help or what?

Comment: @Flob The last advice I can give you (in your precise case) is not to express your constraints in level terms. Instead, express them in relative terms. Using your other question, I mean, do `return [-1 + z[0]/T, -1 + z[1]/R]`. Cheers

Comment: hm, i just realized that my old question contains some errors. Well. Thank you for your help, i guess i'll have no other choice than to add the code to this question even though i wanted to avoid that

Comment: @Kanak Added complete code to copy and paste and reproduce my error above, if you`re still interested

Answer (score 1):

You should try defining explicitly your function before optimizing it, that way you can check for domain more easily.

Essentially you have a function of T and R. this worked for me:

```
def func_to_solve(TR_vector, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    T, R = TR_vector   # what you are trying to find
    w_x = approximate_w(R)
    t_x = approximate_t(w_x, T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3)
    return (calc_2([t_x, w_x], T, R, r_1, r_2, r_3))

def solve(TR, r_1, r_2, r_3):
    sol = optimize.fsolve(func_to_solve, x0=TR, args=(r_1, r_2, r_3))
    return sol
```

Also, replace `m.exp` by `np.exp`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read all of that stuff. I forgot to explain this: even though `func` theoretically is supposed to calculate `T, R` given `t` and `w`, i have to use it the other way around. It's a bit clunky, but i simply don't manage to rewrite the function so that it accepts `T, R` to calculate `t, w` - it's a bit too much for my mediocre mathematical expertise ;))

Comment: The most "mathematically correct" way would be to put that function implicitly and let the program work it.. of course this is numerically expensive. I understood that you used an approximation to avoid this. In any case, if you go with your pseudo-explicit function it is a good practice to define it before optimizing it: this way you can A) plot it and check for domain issues, B) solve it using it different optimizacion algorithms. You can always use something like `scipy.optimize.minimize` wich allows you to use boundaries